# When I try to view Excel in browser I got error We don't know what happened, but something went wrong

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

When I try to view Excel in the browser I got error We don't know what happened, but something went wrong. When I try to edit file is ok?

In the event log I get:

> There was an error in communicating with Excel Calculation Services Event ID 5240

In SharePoint logs I get:

> UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres...   aebbdc9c-56ca-709f-391c-710ea0adc736

I try a few things:

http://sureshpydi.blogspot.in/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-excel-services-we-dont.html
http://spbliss.blogspot.com/2014/07/we-dont-know-what-happened-but.html
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/37fd62ce-9278-491a-92ec-4f27f70c6df4/error-in-communicating-with-excel-calculation-services

I use SharePoint Server 2013

Comment: Try it with a different browser, I usually get those in Firefox too, but in IE, it works.

Comment: It happends in all browser.

Comment: we recently faced the issue after splitting content database...then we tried like this http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2014/03/the-workbook-cannot-be-opened.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, this issue is about Excel Service application and Excel Calculation Services.

Please try to restart Excel Calculation Services in manage services on server.

If this issue still exists, you can try to recreate excel service application.

Answer (score 0):

Open Microsoft Excel, go to file & click on "Open". You can fine the option "Share Point", when you select the share point it will display the sites which you seen earlier. From that you can select your files & checkout for edit.