# Excel Web Part error message in SP2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, error, excel-services

I have a SharePoint 2013 Team site with Excel Services web parts.

Lately, I see the Excel Web parts perfectly (in Israel) but in the same time my colleagues (in USA) seeing error messages instead of the Excel Web Parts.

The error is

> We don't know what happened but something went wrong. Could you please try that again?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, this issue is about Excel Service application and Excel Calculation Services.

Please try to restart Excel Calculation Services in manage services on server.

If this issue still exists, you can try to recreate excel service application.

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126528/when-i-try-to-view-excel-in-browser-i-got-error-we-dont-know-what-happened-but/198395#198395). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

I have used the following link to solve similar issue. Excel Calculation Services must be started and Excel Services service application must be created.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-excel-services

I hope this helps,

Haileleoul Gudeta